# vue.js not rendering a component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

This is my html:

```
<div id="modalComponent">
    <remodal-designs v-binds:designid="1074"></remodal-designs>
</div>
```

This is my scripts in the html:

```
<script src="{{ FuImg::asset('js/libs/vue.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ FuImg::asset('js/vue_components/remodal_designs.js') }}"></script>
```

And this is my Vue js component:

```
Vue.component('remodal-designs', {

    template : '<div id="modaldesigns" class="cp-remodal remodal" :data-remodal-id="designid">\
                    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>\
                    <div class="container">\
                        <div class="row no-gutter">\
                            <div class="col-sm-6">\
                                <div class="cp-tab-menu active">\
                                    Camisetas Premium\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="col-sm-6">\
                                <div class="cp-tab-menu">\
                                   Camisetas Basic\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
    ',

    props : ['designid'],



});
```

The component is not rendering. When I open the chrome browser and use Ctrl + U to see the code, nothing is being done.
[image]

The Chrome console not return errors.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: the vue console report this

```
[Vue warn]: failed to compile template:

<div id="modalComponent">
    <remodal-designs v-bind:designid="5rpexo1zwci6"></remodal-designs>
</div>

- invalid expression: v-bind:designid="1074"


(found in root instance)
```

Comment: Don't use the minified version in development otherwise you won't get all the console errors. Change to the non minified version and see if you get any errors.

Comment: @craig_h I edited the main post

Comment: Could you add the `data` you are using in your main vue instance?

Comment: You just need to have `designid="1074"`, remove `v-bind` as you are not assigning it to any vue data variable.

Comment: and what is in your main.js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, remove `v-bind`:

```
<div id="modalComponent">
    <remodal-designs designid="1074"></remodal-designs>
</div>
```

[v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) is used when you dynamically bind one or more attributes or a component prop to an expression or vue data. Here as you are passing a constant so it is not needed.